# How to compile definitions in c++'s header file to IR in LLVM JIT Module?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, jit, llvm-ir

I am writing my own language using LLVM's JIT, some class will implement by c++, such as `List`, `Map`, and so on.
I can compile these c++ files to object file and then add them to JIT for linking, but when i use them in my language, i need to know it's LLVM type, such as:

```cpp
var data = new List<int>();
data.push(3);
```

when i implement `var data = new List<int>()`, i need to know `List`'s struct type, and then alloca memory for it, but it's c++ code, i cannot know it.

So how to create StructType(LLVM IR) of `List`, in LLVM JIT? I don't what to write it by hand.